# Can I call the DC of the hidden child dialog?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, paint

There are three child dialogs attached to the bottom of the main dialog.

When dialog1 is in the `SW_SHOW` state and dialog2 is in `SW_HIDE`, I want to bring dialog2 DC, screen and capture it.

The entire screen is captured, but if the child dialog changes, the changed dialog is captured.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
MainTrendGraphDlg *pDlg = (MainTrendGraphDlg*)::AfxGetMainWnd();
// MainTrendGraphDlg is dialog2

CClientDC hdcSys(pDlg);

int x_size = ::GetDeviceCaps(hdcSys, HORZRES);
int y_size = ::GetDeviceCaps(hdcSys, VERTRES);
HBITMAP hBitmap; // <-- The image represented by hBitmap

// Initialize DCs
HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcSys); // Create compatible DC 

void *ptrBitmapPixels; // <-- Pointer variable that will contain the potinter for the pixels

// Create hBitmap with Pointer to the pixels of the Bitmap
BITMAPINFO bi; HDC hdc;
ZeroMemory(&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFO));
bi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
bi.bmiHeader.biWidth = x_size;
bi.bmiHeader.biHeight = -y_size;  //negative so (0,0) is at top left
bi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
bi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
hdc = GetDC(NULL);
hBitmap = CreateDIBSection(hdc, &bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, &ptrBitmapPixels, NULL, 0);
// ^^ The output: hBitmap & ptrBitmapPixels

// Set hBitmap in the hdcMem 
SelectObject(hdcMem, hBitmap);

// Set matBitmap to point to the pixels of the hBitmap
matDlgCap = Mat(y_size, x_size, CV_8UC4, ptrBitmapPixels, 0);
//                ^^ note: first it is y, then it is x. very confusing

// Now update the pixels using BitBlt
BitBlt(hdcMem, 0, 0, x_size, y_size, hdcSys, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

imwrite("ScreenShot.jpg", matDlgCap, JPEG_QUALITY);
```

Comment: You can try using `PrintWindow()` to get the child dialog to print itself to a memory DC that you provide, however whether it works or not depends on whether the controls on the dialog support the `WM_PRINTCLIENT` message or not.

Comment: And even than the underlying window might have some code that prevents or "optimizes" pints when it is not fully visible or hidden.